# Lost setting of the custom field when editing a page

Tags: 8, plugins

I created a content type with my own custom field as described in [Why do I get this error when I save my custom field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269087)

The insertion of an item with this content type works, but when I want to modify the article I verified that I lose my custom field setting (it's a select box).

What is the method to keep the setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code in the mentioned question, you need to define `#default_value` property and assign the `$value` variable to it like this:

```
public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $value = isset($items[$delta]->value) ? $items[$delta]->value : '';
    $client   = \Drupal::httpClient();
    $request = $client->get('http://localhost:8083/regionilist');
    $response = json_decode($request->getBody());

    $element += [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Select element'),
      '#options' => $response,
      '#suffix' => '<div class="custom-field-widget"></div>',
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['edit-custom-field-widget']],
      '#attached' => [
        'library' => [
          'custom_field/my_js_custom_field',
        ],
      ],
      '#default_value` => $value,
    ];

    return ['value' => $element];
  }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly the comments for the other answer, it should be `json_decode($request->getBody(), TRUE)`.